# Can I send a mass text in Hangouts?

Tags: google-hangouts

Is there a way to send a text to more than one recipient in the new Hangouts/GVoice integrated app?

I see how you can send a plain (phone) SMS to multiple recipients, but can you do it using through the Google Voice number(note, I don't want a MMS group text. Just a plain SMS)

Answer (score -1):

Go in **hangouts** -> in the **list** of all your **conversation** -> **click** on the "**plus**" in the **top right corner** -> then **select** a **contact**. Now a new screen will appear and a **grey button** will show "**add someone else**" -> **click** on it and you will be able to **add other contacts**.

Hope it will help.

Comment: No it doesn't. It does that only when sending through Network SMS or through a Google+ Hangout, not Google Voice SMS